# Why would association.build not assign parent_id to it child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I've got the following models:

In plan.rb

```
has_many :tickets
```

and in ticket.rb

```
belongs_to :plan
validates_presence_of :plan_id
```

When executing the following code in the controller

```
@plan.tickets.build( ... )
@plan.save
```

save fails with error_message for ticket: plan can't be blank. (plan is valid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this happen when my object was new and unsaved when I called `build` on it.

`build` assigns the `plan_id`, and if `@plan`'s id is nil, then your ticket's `plan_id` will be nil. Because `build` doesn't validate or save, you don't find out until later.

Other methods of adding an associated object to an unsaved object seem to remember that it's unsaved and set the id appropriately. So try this:

```
 @plan.tickets << Ticket.new(...)
 @plan.save
```

Comment: So it's impossible to have such validation, build parent, build relation child than save the parent and haven't error messages at the same time?